# How to refer to buttons on ApplicationBar in Windows Phone development

Tags: c#, windows-phone-7, windows-phone-8

In my Windows Phone application, I have some buttons on my ApplicationBar. In some cases buttons are hidden, in some cases buttons are disabled and in other cases all buttons are visible.

The way I currently use to refer to a button on my ApplicationBar (for example, if I have application logic that needs to disable it) is the following:

```
ApplicationBar.Buttons[1] as ApplicationBarIconButton;
```

I do not like this approach because it refers to the index of a button. If the list of buttons is relatively dynamic, this is asking for trouble.

Does anyone have a recommended way of referring to a button on ApplicationBar?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

What I usually do is I define buttons of interest as properties on a class, for example:

```
private ApplicationBarIconButton SaveButton { get; set; }
```

When the page is loaded, I keep the reference to the given button while constructing the application bar (programmatically):

```
SaveButton = new ApplicationBarIconButton(new Uri(...)) { Text = "Save" };
ApplicationBar.Buttons.Add(SaveButton);
```

This way the button is always available for manipulations via the property access.

Comment: I can understand doing this with a private field, but using a public property doesn't seem a great idea.

Comment: @PaulAnnetts Thanks, I've changed the access modifier. And I always prefer using properties over fields, for a number of reasons.

Comment: +1 on answer. I typically use fields on private (as I can always easily check what code is changing the field), property everywhere else.

Comment: Great idea, volpav - so if I want to edit the button after adding it, I will simply edit through the property... right? What if I want to remove the button from the ApplicationBar?

Comment: @NielsBrinch You're correct, you can edit the button through the property. If you want to remove the button, you can call `ApplicationBar.Buttons.Remove(SaveButton)` (or cast the `Buttons` to `IList` first if the `Remove` method is implemented explicitly. Sorry, can't check right now by myself).